# Two-finger Scroll only works on bottom of touchpad

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

I just switched to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and am having trouble with two-finger scroll on my touchpad.  It only seems to work when I initiate the scrolling from the bottom of the touchpad. If i place my fingers in the center of the touchpad it just controls the mouse pointer.

I have searched around and it seems the two finger option is boolean, but is there a way to edit the effective area of the touchpad where it picks up two finger scrolling over the entirety of the toucpad?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Do you have enabled in Settings --> Mouse & Touchpad -> Two Finger Scrolling ?

Comment: I do.  It is enabled.  My issue is that I have to start the motion from the bottom of the touch pad.  It is really annoying and makes it hard when I have to swipe down.  I'd like the whole touchpad to recognize when I put two fingers on to scroll.

Comment: maybe you can try this https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma.. I know the touchpad should work without installing anything, but this may help you because you have different options for the touchpad && you can change the config file to specify how you will use it...